# Verify that the expression getchar() != EOF is 0 or 1

Tags: c, eof, getchar

**Problem**

> Verify that the expression `getchar() != EOF` is `0` or `1`.

**Approach**

I have tried to write a program which will first take an input other than `EOF` and thus will print the value `1`. Next it will take `EOF` as input and will print `0`.

```
/* Program to verify that the value of the expression getchar() != EOF is 0 or 1 */

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Inputting something other than EOF, value of the expression is %d\n", getchar() != EOF);
    printf("Inputting EOF, value of the expression is %d\n", getchar() != EOF);
    printf("It is verified that the expression getchar() != EOF is 0 or 1.\n");
    return  0;
}`
```

**Issue:**

But the when I give an input it does not print the first line and waits for the next input. It directly prints all the lines. How can I make the second line take the next input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is due to the working principle of [`getchar()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar). It will start reading only after <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key pressed, and in that case, the next `getchar()` (in the second `printf()`) will read the *newline*(`\n`) from the input buffer and won't wait for any *user* input.

Solution: add one more `getchar()` call before the second `printf()`. This will *eat* the `\n`.